# Can a signal below -176 dbm be decoded?

Tags: electrical-engineering, rf-electronics

Can a signal below -176 dbm, which is 1.6 db below thermal noise at room temperature, be decoded irrespective of the modulation type?

Answer (score 2):

No, not irrespective of modulation type. If you know that you need to deal with signals like that, you pick a modulation scheme that provides "gain" in the demodulation process.

For example, GPS uses [direct-sequence spread spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct-sequence_spread_spectrum), which allows the wideband energy of the signal to be "refocused" to a narrow bandwidth, providing a huge amount of gain over the thermal noise.